# EWS Authentication

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, basic-authentication

I have 2 question related to EWS authentication techniques:-
1. Does EWS basic Authentication supports 2 step verification method?
2. Does oAuth type Authentication is supported on lower EWS Exchange Server version like 2007 and 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Exchange uses IIS and the underlying O/S and Active Directory for authentication so "EWS Basic Authentication" is just the standard basic Auth feature that comes from IIS . I would suggest http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-web-services-bypass-multi-factor-authentication/ which goes into detail more what is and isn't available by default.
2. No oAuth was a feature added in Exchange 2013 and wasn't back-ported to older versions of Exchange